# Selecting only updated record in delta

Tags: python, sqlite

Trying to compare 2 tables in the same db. 
Table 1 is the main historical table, table 2 is the temporary table with new data rcvd from server and used to update table 1.

Need to output the items in table 1 that have a change in one of the fields on table 2.

i.e.
table 1(Services)

```
Service - folder- s2 - Real - s4
astatus - on    - on - on - on
```

table 2(Services2)

```
Service - folder - s2 - Real  - s4
astatus - on     - on - off - on
```

So I need the output to indicate that Real in astatus table 1 is off (again table 2 is just the reference temp table with new data to update table 1)
I have all the updates and remaining code done. But i'm stuck on this comparison part...

my code is as follows:

```
cursor.execute("""Select inner.compare FROM
    (Select a.Real = aReal, b.Real = bReal
    FROM Services a
    JOIN Services2 b
    ON
    (lower(a.Service || a.Folder) = lower(b.Service || b.Folder)))inner.compare
    WHERE inner.astat != inner.bstat""")
print inner.compare
```

Comment: You need to find only records in temp table that is having update to any field in historical table?

Comment: the tables should be identical for the most part other than adds/deletes...

so the temp table is current data rcvd from the server... It is used to update table 1 with new/missing data... but i need to know what the "Real" field of an instance in table 1 is different than the "Real" field of the same instance in table 2....

Comment: how about `select * from services a minus select * from services2 b` as query, if both table have same table structure.

Comment: @WoodChopper `EXCEPT`

Comment: Does `except` return what you want?

Comment: I was able to get what I wanted with the following code:

SELECT a.*
FROM Services a
JOIN Services2 b
ON
(lower(a.Service || a.Folder) = lower(b.Service || b.Folder))
WHERE a.Real != b.Real

I guess the next part of this project is to figure out how to insert/export this output to a text file...

Answer (score 1):

```
Select b.*
FROM Services a
JOIN Services2 b
ON
(lower(a.Service || a.Folder) = lower(b.Service || b.Folder))
WHERE a.Real_Time_State != b.Real_Time_State
```

This was the code that gave me the output I was looking for. Thanks for the help!